# Anomaly detection for increasing series of numbers

Tags: statistics, data-science, series, anomaly-detection

I have a series of data, where the value of Count keeps increasing.
Here, there are 4 outliers (manually detected by observation) - 3 times the values of 682 and a value of 14016.
Is there any technique in Python I can use to detect these outliers?

| Date | Count | Anomaly? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9/29/2019 | 11462 |  |
| 10/30/2019 | 12782 |  |
| 11/28/2019 | 686 | anomaly |
| 2/28/2020 | 13222 |  |
| 3/30/2020 | 13305 |  |
| 4/29/2020 | 13316 |  |
| 5/30/2020 | 14016 | anomaly |
| 6/29/2020 | 13372 |  |
| 7/30/2020 | 13487 |  |
| 8/30/2020 | 13519 |  |
| 9/30/2020 | 13553 |  |
| 10/30/2020 | 686 | anomaly |
| 11/29/2020 | 13577 |  |
| 12/26/2020 | 13580 |  |
| 1/30/2021 | 13594 |  |
| 2/27/2021 | 13594 |  |
| 3/30/2021 | 686 | anomaly |
| 4/29/2021 | 686 | anomaly |
| 5/30/2021 | 13619 |  |
| 6/11/2021 | 13619 |  |

Comment: How are these anomaly defined. `686` seems to be a very small number compared to others and I can see why it might be an outlier but why `14016`? If you have a bigger dataset you can try to apply different [classification](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classifier_comparison.html) algorithms / [novelty](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html) detection algorithms for your purpose.

Comment: This is an series of numbers that is supposed to be in the ascending order. While 14016 is greater than 13316, it is an anomaly and an incorrect value. The correct value was 13372.

Answer (score 0):

Transform the series of counts into a series of differences between the counts. Then you can easily model these kinds of anomalies. In your example it seems like considering any difference under 0 to be an anomaly would work.
If the expected rate of increase is somewhat constant, or at least reasonably bounded one could also put an upper threshold on the diff to consider it anomalous.

I see that the number of days between your datapoints is not entirely regular. Then one could also normalize the difference to take this into account, by dividing by number of days since last datapoint.

Pandas and Numpy both have functions `diff` that can be used to do this transformation.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. But here for the change 14016 -> 13372, 14016 is an anomaly.
And for 12782 -> 686, 686 is the anomaly. In both cases the difference is -ve but in the first case, the first number is the anomaly and in the second case, the second number is. How can we get an algo to figure this out automatically.

14016 is actually an anomaly because if you exclude it, the series is increasing. 
686 is a huge deviation and something i can detect easily using z-score etc.

Comment: -> 14016 might be spottable as a too large increase compared to normal rate?

Comment: An complimentary approach is to analyze with a window of say 3-9 long, compute rate changes locally, and then a point inside something deviates from the median by too much, it is considered anomalous

Comment: 14016 is considered as an anomaly only when looking at the subsequent and prior numbers together and spotting that those are in an ascending order whereas 14016 does not fit that order.
Thanks for the idea to analyse with a few records and find their anomalies rather than checking this over the whole series.